# vb.net Text File ReadLine

Tags: vb.net

I have a text file I am trying to read and place into a datatable. The file looks like the below:

```
Control 1 
- 1 Next line 
- 1 Next Line 
    1  Same line 

Control 2
- 2 Next line 
- 2 Next Line 
     2 Same line
```

I want to structure the data like the below:

```
Title | Data 
Control1, - 1 Next line - 1 Next line 1 Same line 
Control2, - 2 Next line - 2 Next line 2 Same line 


    Do
                Dim strInputFileLine As String = srReader.ReadLine()
                If strInputFileLine Is Nothing Then Exit Do


                If strInputFileLine.Contains("Control 1") Then
                    'How Do I get the Text before Control 2 Begins???


                End If
loop
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
Dim strInputFileLine As String
Dim nextLine,text As String
text = ""
        Do
            strInputFileLine  = srReader.ReadLine()
            If strInputFileLine Is Nothing Then Exit Do


            If strInputFileLine.Contains("Control 1") Then
                Do
                    nextLine = srReader.Readline()
                    If nextLine = "Control 2" Then Exit Do 'you can even use .Contains
                    Else
                        text += nextLine
                loop
            End If
       loop
```

Comment: agreed - i thought of that after i asked. Thank you.